# Characteristic polynomial of matrix with real coefficients

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reading a lecture note about matrix.

Let $p_A(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$.

Can we say if $p_A(x) = p_A(-x)$, then $p_A(x)$ is a real coefficient polynomial?

Comment: If $p(x) = p(-x)$ then $p$ is even (by definition) but we can find even polynomials with complex coefficients.  $p(x) = ix^2$ would be an example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your title is ambiguous. I have taken it to mean that the matrix has real entries....

It is restrictive, but perhaps not as much as you think. In any case, a real matrix has a characteristic polynomial with real coefficients.  Now, the characteristic polynomial of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is 
$$  x^4 + 4  $$ while the roots are
$$  1+i, 1-i, -1+i, -1-i  $$